# Is there a way to host css file that is in bitbucket repository

Tags: css, git, file, hosting, bitbucket

I have a css file in bitbucket repository . Is there a way to host it so that I can consume the url from different applications/ projects and changes pushed to the repository gets reflected in the hosted file.

Read about rawgit, but looks like it works for github alone. I need for bitbucket.
It will be great if someone  can  give an insight to how to handle production and development urls for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can link to a file like this:

`https://bitbucket.org/kevinburke/better-hn-filter/raw/master/script.js`

For the file `script.js` in [this](https://bitbucket.org/kevinburke/better-hn-filter) repository.